# 'io.h': No such file or directory during "pip install netifaces"

Tags: python, c

I tried to install netifaces in Python 3.6.2 by:

```
pip install netifaces
```

but when I run it in cmd, I get this error:

> c:\users\seyed_vahid\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
>       error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try running the command in a Developer Command Prompt window? The paths to VS include files aren't set in a regular command window. On Windows 10, just type "developer command prompt" in the search control on the taskbar, and the shortcut should be the top result.

Comment: I  running the command in a Developer Command Prompt window,but again get top error

Comment: I don't think it's possible not to install the UCRT when you check Visual C++ in the Features list in VS2015 setup, but I could be mistaken. In your Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 window, do a SET command. Does the INCLUDE path have C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.[version].0\ucrt in it somewhere? If not, then rerun setup (go to Apps in Control Panel, select VS 2015, choose Change) and in Features, in Windows and Web Development, under Universal Windows App Development Tools, check the latest Windows 10 SDK. Update, reboot, retry.

Comment: On the other hand, if the ucrt directory IS in the INCLUDE path, then you could try to run the Developer Command Prompt as an administrator. Open the Visual Studio 2015 folder in the Start menu, right-click the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 shortcut, then choose More > Run as administrator. This seems unlikely to be the solution, since I wouldn't expect the pip install command to find cl.exe if it was a problem, but it probably won't hurt to try.

Answer (score 3):

Try open VS Installer and install something like

> VC++ 2015 v140 toolset

Comment: Installing this toolset through Visual Studio Installer fixed the issue for me, thanks.

Comment: for those using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) as package manager on windows `choco install vcbuildtools`

Answer (score 2):

I just had a frustrating day trying to find a way to make this work as well. (I use the Visual Studio, Python, Windows combination).

When getting build errors during pip installs (io.h, rc.exe not found etc), in my case with netifaces / pychromecast (but the issue is the same for all), make the following changes / additions  to your environment variables:

INCLUDE (create if needed)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\SDK\include\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\SDK\include\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\SDK\include\um
```

LIB (create if needed)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\SDK\lib
```

Add to PATH

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\SDK\bin
```

After making these changes I was able to install / compile things properly