# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip

I'm trying to install a program from pip install SimPEGEM1D and I getting the error "  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory"
[image]
I already have tried the suggestion from ['io.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904828/io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

but didn't work, I have visual studio 2017 and anaconda. I went to my directory and there is no io.h file there, so did I miss something when I installed visual studio? How do I fix  that?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cython- Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cython-cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Update or reinstall Visual Studio https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

I'm sure you've already solved this problem given the time discrepancy. However, I ran into this problem today and found my solution by reinstalling Visual Studio.

[image: Visual Studio version that worked for me.]

Error I was receiving:

```
h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
```

Please note I also tried the following before reinstalling Visual Studio:

1. Pip/Pip3
2. Wheels
3. Setuptools
4. (verified Environment PATH/variables)

As of current Time and Date, you will be able to find the most up-to-date version of
Visual Studio cpp-Build-Tools here:https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/