# Cannot open include file: 'io.h' / Cannot include file:'basetsd.h'

Tags: python

I am trying to install the Python wrapper for my camera from [here](https://github.com/Photometrics/PyVCAM).
My install command is

```
python setup.py install
```

and I am getting the following error

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\mesoSPIM Workstation\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\numpy\core\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Photometrics\PVCamSDK\/inc/" -IC:\Users\Public\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\Public\Anaconda3\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" /EHsc /Tpsrc/pyvcam/pvcmodule.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\src/pyvcam/pvcmodule.obj
pvcmodule.cpp
C:\Users\Public\Anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

The installation requires the latest version of C++ build tools which I have installed using the [Visual Studio Installer.](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)
I have tried to implement the different solutions detailed here: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory/56811119?newreg=1bd7811c813c4a4e9db7ac371e93637d), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54027942/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904828/io-h-no-such-file-or-directory-during-pip-install-netifaces)

These solutions in general have to do reinstalling VC++ or installing Win 10/11 SDK. After manually adding environment variables as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40810172/21471109), I get a similar error where the code cannot open the 'basestd.h' file:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
```

Also to note: I am not able to reproduce these errors on another PC with the same configuration. The installation works fine there.

I am using Anaconda3 and a Win 11 PC.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and it was caused by pyconfig.h in anaconda folder:

```
C:\Users\...\miniconda3\include\pyconfig.h(207): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
```

I fixed error by commenting that line:

```
    /* define some ANSI types that are not defined in earlier Win headers */
    #if _MSC_VER >= 1200
    /* This file only exists in VC 6.0 or higher */
    #include <basetsd.h>    <<-------------------
    #endif
```