# pip install web3 issue with fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, solidity, fatal-error, web3py

I am having an issue with fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory,

when I run `pip install web3` on a bash terminal

the process will start to install then hit me with

```
 C:\Users\jnkat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.30.30705\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

I've downloaded everything I've read about to fix this in visual studio installer as well as set an include path.

if someone could shed some light and explain to me what may be the problem why it can't open that io.h file that would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['io.h': No such file or directory during "pip install netifaces"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904828/io-h-no-such-file-or-directory-during-pip-install-netifaces)

Comment: now i am getting ' fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory'

Comment: Try to install MSVC C++ Build Tools (could be found in Visual studio installer) helps me on my computer.